# Calculate speed (first derivative in time) of time series

Tags: r, xts

I would like to compute the speed from data in `xts` time series. My data looks like this (command bellow generates sample, actual data is much larger).

```
measurement <- xts(c(7.9, 8.6, 12.7, 13.3), 
                   as.POSIXct(c("2016-02-24 06:00:00",
                                "2016-02-24 07:30:00",
                                "2016-02-24 09:15:00",
                                "2016-02-24 11:15:00")))
names(measurement) <- "pos"

head(measurement)
                     pos
2016-02-24 06:00:00  7.9
2016-02-24 07:30:00  8.6
2016-02-24 09:15:00 12.7
2016-02-24 11:15:00 13.3
```

If I use `diff` I am getting the changes between successive values.

```
diff(measurement)
                    pos
2016-02-24 06:00:00  NA
2016-02-24 07:30:00 0.7
2016-02-24 09:15:00 4.1
2016-02-24 11:15:00 0.6
```

However, I would like to take time into account and compute speed (e.g. change in time period). I have tried using the following dirty road.

```
measurement$time  <- as.numeric(index(measurement))
measurement$speed  <- diff(measurement$pos) / diff(measurement$time) * 3600

head(measurement)
                    pos  time       speed
2016-02-24 06:00:00  7.9 1456290000        NA
2016-02-24 07:30:00  8.6 1456295400 0.4666667
2016-02-24 09:15:00 12.7 1456301700 2.3428571
2016-02-24 11:15:00 13.3 1456308900 0.3000000
```

There must be a simpler and more elegant way to do this. Have in mind that I am still new to R and might be missing something.

Comment: I think your solution is good. Not sure you'll find anything significantly more elegant or compact. However, SO is full of surprises and maybe somebody finds something that you would prefer.

Comment: Could you post example data in a format we can import easily into R? I'm not sure what you mean by speed - are you just referring to the change in `pos` over the change in `time`?

Comment: I have updated the question with a command to generate sample xts data. My result should be `diff(pos)/diff(time)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware that either base R or the `xts` package provides a way to directly calculate a physical rate in the way you're doing.  A bit more straightforward way to do the `speed` calculation in hours might be

```
# alternative time conversion 
  del_t <- diff(index(measurement))
  units(del_t) <- "hours"
  measurement$speed_hr <- diff(measurement$pos, na.pad=FALSE)/as.numeric(del_t)
```

The units of time returned by `diff` can be specified so in this case can be set to  `hours`.

More generally, your speed calculation has discontinuities at the data points.  In some situations, there would also be a requirement for continuity of `speed` across the data points.  `speed` could then be calculated using R's `splinefun` routine which can return not only the spline interpolation for position but also the first derivative giving an approximation of speed which is both continuous and depends upon more than two of neighboring data points.  Code could look like

```
# provides continuity of speed at data points
# perform cubic spline fit
  spline_fit <- splinefun(x=index(measurement), y=measurement$pos, method="natural")

# add spline speeds to measurements
  measurement$spline_spd <- spline_fit(index(measurement), deriv=1)*3600
```

The spline speeds disagree with the speeds from the original calculation but this seems to be a result of the constraint on continuity at the data points.  A plot may help to clarify this.

```
# make a sequence of plot times for spline fits
  spline_times <- seq(start(measurement), end(measurement), length.out=40)
# plot positions
  par(mfcol=c(2,1))
  plot(spline_times, spline_fit(spline_times, deriv=0), col="red", type="b", 
       main="Positions", xlab = "Time", ylab="Pos")
  points(index(measurement), measurement$pos, type="p", pch=19, cex=1.1)
  legend("topleft", legend = c("-- pos data","-- spline pos interpolations"), 
         text.col = c("black","red"), y.intersp=.2, yjust=3., bty="n", cex=1.3)
# plot speeds
  plot(spline_times, spline_fit(spline_times, deriv=1)*3600, col="red", type="b",
       main="Speeds", xlab="Time", ylab="Speed")
  lines(index(measurement), measurement$speed, type="b", pch=19, cex=1.1)
  legend("topleft", legend = c("-- speed calculation","-- spline speed interpolations"), 
       text.col = c("black","red"), y.intersp=.2, yjust=3., bty="n", cex=1.3)
```

[image]

Four data points is really too few for a good spline fit but perhaps this conveys the general idea.

Comment: Your solution with splines does exactly what I wanted to achieve. Yes, four data points is really not much for a good spline, but my datasets do not have much more points per day (observation time for speed is each day). I believe the `units(del_t) <- "hours"` is not needed in the alternative time conversion as the difference is already given in hours. Thanks for pointing to `na.pad=FALSE`.